# One controller in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, orientation, landscape

I have an app, which consists of one Tab bar controller which contains 4 navigation controllers. I can't find any solution to have one controller in the hierarchy of the navigation controllers to be only in landscape mode. All other controllers suppose to be portrait. Appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In the `viewDidLoad():` of the navigation controller that you want to be landscape, include:

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

be sure to add the following override too

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: I added this code to the navigation controller, it is not working on the iOS 8, shouldAutorotate never called. Seems that this is a big problem in the latest iOS.

Answer (score 0):

so i tried the following solution and it worked for me:

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
var currViewController: UIViewController?

func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationForWindows window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
  if currViewController is MyCustomController {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft
  } else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
  }
}
```

In MyCustomController.swift:

```
let oAppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()
  oAppDelegate.currViewController = self
}
```